# Index mapping having date format, using curl throws parsing exception

Tags: datetime, elasticsearch, curl, elasticsearch-7

Trying to specify format (in index mapping) for the `date` field in ES 7.6. Any of these are not accepted:

```
        "createdAt" : {
          "type" : "date",
          "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'''T'''HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ"
        },
```

```
        "createdAt" : {
          "type" : "date",
          "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ"
        },
```

Error is always the same:

> "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
>       "reason" : "Invalid format: [yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZZ]: Unknown pattern letter: T",

Here is full example to reproduce:

```
curl -X DELETE "localhost:9200/example?pretty"
curl -X PUT   "localhost:9200/example/_mappings?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d' {
      "dynamic": false,
      "properties" : {
        "name" : {
          "type" : "text"
        },
        "createdAt" : {
          "type" : "date",
          "format" : "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss.SSSZ"
        }
      }
}'
```

Comment: it's even before inserting data, just mapping itself.

Comment: @Lupanoide updated question - added full example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check various supported date format on https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html:

**The correct format for your date format is below**

`"format" : "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss.SSSZ"` (no `-` in between yyyyMMdd)

I just created an index with below format, so that you can try yourself:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "date": {
        "type": "date" ,
        "format" : "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss.SSSZ" --> notice there is no `-` in yyyyymmdd
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT:- As per the latest update from OP, he is using the `curl` command to create the indices, hence he needs to escape the apostrophe('') present in the date `T` field.**

Proper `curl` command would like below:

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:9500/example/_mappings?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d' {
      "dynamic": false,
      "properties" : {
        "name" : {
          "type" : "text"
        },
        "createdAt" : {
          "type" : "date",
          "format" : "yyyyMMdd'\''T'\''HHmmss.SSSZ" --> notice escape `T`
        }
      }
}'
```

Which gives proper output in curl:

```
{
  "acknowledged" : true
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work...
I tried your example with single and three <'> and getting the same error. "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason" : "Invalid format: [yyyyMMddTHHmmss.SSSZ]: Unknown pattern letter: T", "caused_by" : { "type" : "illegal_argument_exception", "reason" : "Unknown pattern letter: T"}
I even checked with just 'yyyyMMdd' to see that it works in at least some way...

Comment: @user2220154, you are using `curl`, this you should have mentioned in first place :-), anyway updated my answer with proper `curl` command., enjoy

Comment: Thanks for teaching us how to properly escape the 'T' part, I was struggling with this!